# shiny package not getting removed

Tags: r, shiny

I found that I have two shiny packages installed at two different locations.

```
library("shiny", lib.loc="~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3")
library("shiny", lib.loc="/usr/local/lib/R/site-library")
```

I want to remove one of them and tried

```
remove.packages("shiny", lib="~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3")
```

But it do not remove the package, how to do it.

Comment: What version of R are you running? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam `3.3.3`, no error message